# Aurelia app is not launched using au run cli command

Tags: aurelia

i am very new to Aurelia framework, hence following the guide to create project https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager/#setting-up-your-machine
I am using **au -v**
**0.33.1**

But, when i use **au run** to run the app
when i try to open the application in browser blow error message comes, can some one helps me?

```
au run
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'runWebpack'...
(node:5780) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Project is running at http://localhost:8080
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\dist
404s will fallback to /index.html
Finished 'runWebpack'
Hash: 2a2f417dfbd63c84f978
Version: webpack 4.7.0
Time: 16633ms
Built at: 2018-05-05 20:24:50
                                Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   app.2a2f417dfbd63c84f978.bundle.js      3 MiB     app  [emitted]  [big]  app
vendor.2a2f417dfbd63c84f978.bundle.js    489 KiB  vendor  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                           index.html  589 bytes          [emitted]
Entrypoint app [big] = app.2a2f417dfbd63c84f978.bundle.js
Entrypoint vendor [big] = vendor.2a2f417dfbd63c84f978.bundle.js
[./node_modules/aurelia-bootstrapper/dist/native-modules/aurelia-bootstrapper.js] 5.17 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/native-modules/aurelia-loader-webpack.js] 14.4 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-pal/dist/native-modules/aurelia-pal.js] 2.18 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-polyfills/dist/native-modules/aurelia-polyfills.js] 24.4 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js] 585 bytes {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry.js] 1.56 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js] 175 KiB {vendor} {app} [built]
[./node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js-exposed] 65 bytes {vendor} {app} [built]
[./node_modules/process/browser.js] 5.29 KiB {vendor} {app} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {vendor} {app} [built]
[aurelia-framework] ./node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/native-modules/aurelia-framework.js 14 KiB {app} [built]
[aurelia-pal-browser] ./node_modules/aurelia-pal-browser/dist/native-modules/aurelia-pal-browser.js 16.3 KiB {app} [built]
[main] ./src/main.js 5.16 KiB {app} [built]
[0] multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper 52 bytes {app} [built]
[1] multi bluebird 28 bytes {vendor} [built]
    + 262 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  1.36 MiB       0
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.ejs] 890 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /app.2a2f417dfbd63c84f978.bundle.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.2a2f417dfbd63c84f978.bundle.js
× ｢wdm｣: ConcurrentCompilationError: You ran Webpack twice. Each instance only supports a single concurrent compilation at a time.
    at Compiler.run (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:151:37)
    at rebuild (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\context.js:81:24)
    at done (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\context.js:59:7)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:18:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at emitRecords.err (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:203:22)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:315:39)
    at emitAssets.err (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:197:10)
    at hooks.afterEmit.callAsync.err (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:301:14)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at asyncLib.forEach.err (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:298:27)
    at done (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2854:11)
    at F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2805:7
    at MemoryFileSystem.writeFile (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\MemoryFileSystem.js:328:9)
    at writeOut (F:\AureliaWorkspace\sampleApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:284:29)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant error:

> ConcurrentCompilationError: You ran Webpack twice. Each instance only supports a single concurrent compilation at a time.

You're not doing anything wrong here, this is a regression caused by some combination of changes in aurelia-cli and webpack. See this [github issue](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/852)

In short, lazy mode is not working properly. The workaround is to always use the `--watch` flag with `au run`.

`au run --watch` should work.

Comment: yes, i have been observed, with --watch flag only it is working. Thanks for confirming and sharing your thoughts.

Comment: As of date of this comment, run is still not working